# Tomcat 7 with SpringMVC, missing "Server startup" success message

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

Up until recently my catalina.log used to report the following:

```
Mar 19, 2015 4:49:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher1'
Mar 19, 2015 4:49:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]
Mar 19, 2015 4:49:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 53209 ms
```

which I look for during an automated deployment to know whether my servlet started OK. Recently, I no longer get this message in catalina.out. However:

- there are no startup errors
- logging is working
- the server seems to be working perfectly, AFAICT (responds to all requests)
- kill -3  doesn't show anything helpful that I can see

So,

- What might have caused the "Server startup" message to stop being printed (and yet the server to accept connections)?
- In (annotation based) Spring MVC, there a good place where I can place a hook and output a custom "servlet startup success" message?

Answer (score 1):

1. The "standard out" may no longer be going to catalina.out.  What's in your log4j property file? And what are you using to start Tomcat?
2. You could impelement a ServletContextListener to be aware of when the Servlet based application is ready to accept requests.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)